# Dockerrun.aws.json file for private dockerhub image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a rails application built with Docker to Elastic Beanstalk's multi-container service. My Dockerrun.aws.json currently looks like:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "myapp",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myapp-redis",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/myapp-redis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myapp-postgres",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/myapp-postgres"
      }
    }
  ],
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "myapp",
    "key": "config.json"
  },
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "redis",
      "image": "redis:3.0.5",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "Container",
          "value": "redis"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 6379,
          "containerPort": 6379
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "myapp-redis",
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/redis/data",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "postgres",
      "image": "postgres:9.4.5",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "Container",
          "value": "postgres"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5432,
          "containerPort": 5432
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "myapp-postgres",
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "myapp",
      "image": "myrepo/myapp:latest",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "Container",
          "value": "myapp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "myapp",
          "containerPath": "/myapp",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My `config.json` file is at bucket `myapp/config.json` and is formatted like:

```
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "mylongauthtokenhere",
    "email": "me@myemail.com"
  }
}
```

This setup works when I point to a public repo for the `"image": "myrepo/myapp:latest",` line, but when I try to initialize with this config I get errors: `err="Error: image myrepo/myapp:latest not found"` and `ERROR [Instance: i-913b2004] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'`

I've also tried configuing config.json a few different ways with no luck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, when you use this config pointing to a public repo it works, but if you point it a private repo you get the error (everything else is the same)?

Comment: Yep, as far as I can tell the only thing hanging it up is the fact that that's a private repo.

Comment: Can you put the complete content of the auth  I want to see how far it's nested?  Is your config from 1.7 docker or 1.6 & earlier?

Comment: I'm using docker 1.10.3 on my machine. The EB dashboard shows 1.9.1

Comment: See the update to my post.  EB still want the auth file in the old format, not the one generated by docker 1.7 or later.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the version angle though. Checking now to see if launching on another version of docker or altering this file format makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE: the OP found the specific role that was needed. The
>   `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` needed the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
>   policy.

EB runs via  service roles.  These roles need to be granted appropriate permissions to go out and grab the credential file from S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html

Also, I'm guessing your using Docker 1.7 or later locally.

Docker 1.7+ login generates a credential file `config.json` like this:

```
{
 "auths" :
 {
    "server" :
   {
      "auth" : "auth_token",
      "email" : "email"
    }
   }
 }
```

Elastic Beanstalk used to want only the old config object format like this:

```
 {
    "server" :
   {
      "auth" : "auth_token",
      "email" : "email"
    }
   }
```

Notice the missing outer auth block?

Or maybe it's the other way around and ElasticBeanstalk is expecting the newer format if as you note in your OP EB is using docker 1.9.1

You could try to edit this file and re-upload to EB.  See the bottom of this page for details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private

Comment: This is what my file currently looks like right? As noted in the second code block of my question? Or does that still look wrong?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Try to do the opposite, add the outer auth block to the json.  Their documentation is notoriously quirky, maybe now they accept the newer config format

Comment: Ok trying that now

Comment: Hmmm, my EB Dash board is shown using docker 1.11.1, yet I use the old format for the config file

Comment: Also, I remember needing to give Amazon permissions and a enable a trust relationship to give it access S3 to pull the credential file

Comment: Right now I'm creating the EB environment with my personal credentials, which have access to everything in our AWS system. Would I still need to set up a trust in that instance?

Comment: Yes I think you need to look at this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#ecs-config-s3

Comment: EB doesn't run as you

Comment: Got it to work! It was the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role needing the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy. Thanks for your input! If you can edit to include that I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Raskolnikov great! I had a feeling if it wasn't a simple json config formating issue it was going to be not having the proper service role set up -- I find roles and permissions the single most challenging area of AWS.  It would also be nice if EB was a little more up front on the exact issue it hit and why.   I've updated my answer to move the recommendation on checking your service roles to the top and noted the exact role you found to be the issue.